# Photoshop: How to select multiple anchor points without affecting another shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, pen-tool

How can I click+drag to select multiple anchor points on a shape without activating the shape behind it?

Currently, I must first activate the desired layer, then begin the click+drag off the background shape to reach the anchor points I want, otherwise I will activate the background shape.

[image]

Comment: I don't follow you have to select the shape layer before you can move their control points so it should affect each other. Something's missing. Could you maybe edit with a screenshot of your layer panel

Comment: I select the desired shape layer first, it is now active, but then I click+drag around its control points to grab multiple at once, but this action now activates the shape layer behind it, and the desired shape is no longer active.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix for you. With the Direct Select chosen <kbd>A</kbd> change the top to `Select: Active Layers` - it sounds like you've got it on `Select: All Layers` currently.

[image]

Comment: That definitely sounds like it's it. Only problem is I don't have that selection available in my toolbar on CS6

Comment: Some light research suggests that feature wasn't added until CC. Bummer.

Comment: @BigMapIdea really? hmm been a while I guess. Guess all you can do is lock or hide the layers you're not working on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct select tool to command (⌘)-click (Mac) on each anchor point to choose them cumulatively, one-by-one without deselecting any you've already chosen.

That will avoid selecting the line segments between the anchor points that you get when you click-drag over a shape with anchor points or use a lasso over a shape with anchor points.

HACK: Rest your finger on the command (⌘) key as you click the points to reduce the "effort."

Comment: The use of a lasso tool or similar is desired, as suggested by the screenshot. Selecting multiple anchor points cumulatively is a nuisance for complex shapes.